# Threading: Thread.CurrentThread.Name and Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThereadId

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task, threadpool

I was trying to identify some threads by assigning names to them (property: `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name`) but then I realized I could use the `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId`. My question is: if I assign "Thread1" in the property `CurrentThread.Name` and the `CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` would be "1", will this always be true? or the threadpool can assign different ManagedThreadId to the thread with the name "Thread1"?

Comment: Are you using pure `Thread` objects or the `ThreadPool` class?

Comment: I am using the Task/Task<T> class, but for a profiler I am using the System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.managedthreadid.aspx) states:

> The value of the ManagedThreadId property does not vary over time,
>   even if unmanaged code that hosts the common language runtime
>   implements the thread as a fiber.

So I wouldn't worry about the correspondence thread name -> managed thread id breaking.